# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'i18n'

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-i18next

I listen to `languageChanged` event of i18 in `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onLanguageChange = () => {
    // setLanguageChanged(true)
  }

  i18n.on('languageChanged', onLanguageChange)

  return () => {
    i18n.off('languageChanged', onLanguageChange)
  }
}, [])
```

and get the warning:

> `ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'i18n'.`

I don't want to ignore this warning by use `eslint-disable`.

Should I update the dependencies array to `[i18n]`? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have many options here, short of removing `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` linting rule completely.

- You can either ignore the missing dependency by selectively disabling the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule for that line:

  ```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const onLanguageChange = () => {
      // setLanguageChanged(true)
    };

    i18n.on('languageChanged', onLanguageChange);

    return () => {
      i18n.off('languageChanged', onLanguageChange);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  ```
- You can just add the missing dependency `i18n`:

  ```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const onLanguageChange = () => {
      // setLanguageChanged(true);
    };

    i18n.on('languageChanged', onLanguageChange);

    return () => {
      i18n.off('languageChanged', onLanguageChange);
    };
  }, [i18n]);
  ```